# React failed create react app module not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I bought a new pc today.
I installed the latest reccomanded version of NodeJS, installed npm.
I checked if they are installed correctly using the node -v and npm -v and i can see
Node:
v16.13.0
npm:
8.1.0
Then tried to build a new react app with the command **npx create-react-app test-app**. I tried this, then tried to install it globally but i had the same feedback from the error.
So the problem is:
When i lunch the command create-react-app, it crashes giving me this error back. Anyone can explain me what is happening?
The error starts at row 111

Thanks everyone!

```js
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'install',
0 verbose cli   '-g',
0 verbose cli   'coa'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.1.0
2 info using node@v16.13.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 4ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 4ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 5ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 3ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\Progetti\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Amministratore\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Amministratore\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 18ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 18ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
21 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 0ms
22 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 5ms
23 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 3ms
24 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 0ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 30ms
27 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 2ms
28 timing idealTree:init Completed in 9ms
29 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 4ms
30 silly idealTree buildDeps
31 silly fetch manifest coa@*
32 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/coa 76ms (cache hit)
33 silly placeDep ROOT coa@3.1.3 OK for:  want: *
34 silly fetch manifest @types/q@^1.5.1
35 silly fetch manifest chalk@^2.4.1
36 silly fetch manifest q@^1.1.2
37 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fq 24ms (cache hit)
38 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk 24ms (cache hit)
39 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/q 28ms (cache hit)
40 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 130ms
41 silly placeDep node_modules/coa @types/q@1.5.5 OK for: coa@3.1.3 want: ^1.5.1
42 silly placeDep node_modules/coa chalk@2.4.2 OK for: coa@3.1.3 want: ^2.4.1
43 silly placeDep node_modules/coa q@1.5.1 OK for: coa@3.1.3 want: ^1.1.2
44 silly fetch manifest ansi-styles@^3.2.1
45 silly fetch manifest escape-string-regexp@^1.0.5
46 silly fetch manifest supports-color@^5.3.0
47 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles 24ms (cache hit)
48 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/supports-color 24ms (cache hit)
49 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-string-regexp 28ms (cache hit)
50 timing idealTree:node_modules/coa Completed in 44ms
51 timing idealTree:node_modules/coa/node_modules/@types/q Completed in 0ms
52 silly placeDep node_modules/coa ansi-styles@3.2.1 OK for: chalk@2.4.2 want: ^3.2.1
53 silly placeDep node_modules/coa escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 OK for: chalk@2.4.2 want: ^1.0.5
54 silly placeDep node_modules/coa supports-color@5.5.0 OK for: chalk@2.4.2 want: ^5.3.0
55 silly fetch manifest color-convert@^1.9.0
56 silly fetch manifest has-flag@^3.0.0
57 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/color-convert 21ms (cache hit)
58 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/has-flag 23ms (cache hit)
59 timing idealTree:node_modules/coa/node_modules/chalk Completed in 44ms
60 silly placeDep node_modules/coa color-convert@1.9.3 OK for: ansi-styles@3.2.1 want: ^1.9.0
61 silly fetch manifest color-name@1.1.3
62 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/color-name 12ms (cache hit)
63 timing idealTree:node_modules/coa/node_modules/ansi-styles Completed in 18ms
64 silly placeDep node_modules/coa color-name@1.1.3 OK for: color-convert@1.9.3 want: 1.1.3
65 timing idealTree:node_modules/coa/node_modules/color-convert Completed in 3ms
66 timing idealTree:node_modules/coa/node_modules/color-name Completed in 1ms
67 timing idealTree:node_modules/coa/node_modules/escape-string-regexp Completed in 0ms
68 timing idealTree:node_modules/coa/node_modules/q Completed in 0ms
69 silly placeDep node_modules/coa has-flag@3.0.0 OK for: supports-color@5.5.0 want: ^3.0.0
70 timing idealTree:node_modules/coa/node_modules/supports-color Completed in 2ms
71 timing idealTree:node_modules/coa/node_modules/has-flag Completed in 0ms
72 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 245ms
73 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 2ms
74 timing idealTree Completed in 262ms
75 timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 269ms
76 timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 3ms
77 silly reify moves {}
78 timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 1ms
79 timing reify:createSparse Completed in 9ms
80 timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
81 silly audit bulk request {
81 silly audit   coa: [ '3.1.3' ],
81 silly audit   '@types/q': [ '1.5.5' ],
81 silly audit   chalk: [ '2.4.2' ],
81 silly audit   q: [ '1.5.1' ],
81 silly audit   'ansi-styles': [ '3.2.1' ],
81 silly audit   'escape-string-regexp': [ '1.0.5' ],
81 silly audit   'supports-color': [ '5.5.0' ],
81 silly audit   'color-convert': [ '1.9.3' ],
81 silly audit   'color-name': [ '1.1.3' ],
81 silly audit   'has-flag': [ '3.0.0' ]
81 silly audit }
82 silly tarball no local data for coa@https://registry.npmjs.org/coa/-/coa-3.1.3.tgz. Extracting by manifest.
83 timing reifyNode:node_modules/coa/node_modules/escape-string-regexp Completed in 188ms
84 timing reifyNode:node_modules/coa/node_modules/ansi-styles Completed in 189ms
85 timing reifyNode:node_modules/coa/node_modules/has-flag Completed in 191ms
86 timing reifyNode:node_modules/coa/node_modules/supports-color Completed in 192ms
87 timing reifyNode:node_modules/coa/node_modules/@types/q Completed in 194ms
88 timing reifyNode:node_modules/coa/node_modules/color-name Completed in 198ms
89 timing reifyNode:node_modules/coa/node_modules/q Completed in 199ms
90 timing reifyNode:node_modules/coa/node_modules/chalk Completed in 199ms
91 timing reifyNode:node_modules/coa/node_modules/color-convert Completed in 200ms
92 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/coa/-/coa-3.1.3.tgz 223ms (cache miss)
93 timing reifyNode:node_modules/coa Completed in 287ms
94 timing reify:unpack Completed in 287ms
95 timing reify:unretire Completed in 0ms
96 timing build:queue Completed in 6ms
97 info run coa@3.1.3 preinstall node_modules/coa start /B node compile.js & node compile.js
98 info run coa@3.1.3 preinstall { code: 1, signal: null }
99 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 27ms
100 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
101 timing command:install Completed in 762ms
102 verbose stack Error: command failed
102 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
102 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
102 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
102 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
103 verbose pkgid coa@3.1.3
104 verbose cwd C:\Users\Luca\Desktop\Progetti
105 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
106 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "coa"
107 verbose node v16.13.0
108 verbose npm  v8.1.0
109 error code 1
110 error path C:\Users\Amministratore\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coa
111 error command failed
112 error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c start /B node compile.js & node compile.js
113 error node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
113 error   throw err;
113 error   ^
113 error
113 error Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Amministratore\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coa\compile.js'
113 error     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
113 error     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
113 error     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
113 error     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
113 error   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
113 error   requireStack: []
113 error }
113 error node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
113 error   throw err;
113 error   ^
113 error
113 error Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Amministratore\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coa\compile.js'
113 error     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
113 error     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
113 error     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
113 error     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
113 error   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
113 error   requireStack: []
113 error }
114 verbose exit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's working now!

COA got compromised but is now back up again without the malicious code inside.
Check https://github.com/veged/coa/issues/99 for more info.